# How to edit the URL in javascript before setting the 'add to favorite' in IE?

Tags: javascript

I am developing a web site using asp.net and javascript.

In my web site, if the user is trying to set the URL as bookmark (from the favorites menu) from any page other than the home page, I need to set the home page as a bookmark.

So, the url that should pass to the IE built-in function should be the home page url.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible how can you tell what is your home page? If I am visiting `mail.google.com` then what should be my homepage `gmail.com` or `google.com`? I think this idea is not possible.